# C++: is function re-declaration a undefined behavior?

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f(int x = 0) {
    cout << "x:" << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
int main() {
    f();
    int f(int x = 1);
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://ideone.com/qhRvS7)(tested on g++ 5.1):

```
x:0
x:1
```

My question:

1. Is `int f(int x = 1);` a declaration or definition?
2. Is function re-declaration like that a undefined behavior?

Comment: note that `x = 0` and `x = 1` are not 'part of' `f()`, it's just a calling convention that executes in the caller's context. Hence, you might even specify `alloca()` there, the caller will call it, not `f()`...

Comment: Regardless of legality it is tricky, confusing code and as such best avoided IMHO.

Comment: [You need a better compiler or need to turn up the warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ad7569b3bd7556e).  Your missing return statement makes this UB code.

Comment: @NathanOliver Okay... But I think we should focus on `int f(int x = 1);` ...

Comment: @Sayakiss I think including unrelated UB in a question about UB reduces clarity. Why not just add a `return 0;` or smth. to solve that issue? (Or use `void f` instead, w/e you prefer.)

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thanks your advice, I edited my code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From §8.3.6 in [dcl.fct.default](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/wp/html/oct97/decl.html) :

> 4. For non-template functions, default arguments can be added in later declarations of a function in the
>      same scope. Declarations in different scopes have completely distinct sets of default arguments.

Not undefined behaviour. What you're seeing is mandated.